# [NSISUnrestrictedVariable retain]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, memory

I am at a complete lose here.  I get this error when the page finishes loading and it only happens on the ipad.  This error started happening with ios 7.  How can i get the stacktrace for this memory address.

[image]

Comment: In LLVM use the `BT` command. Why are you only seeing assembly code?

Comment: I wish I knew.  This is xcode 4.6.  Am I doing something wrong?  llvm is the console that i can put commands in.  What do i need to put in With CT?  im confused.

Comment: Sorry, `BT` for BackTrace. Is this a iPad running a debug build connected to your computer? You might need to go up the stack to see where in your code this occurs. look at the backtrace in the navigation view.

Comment: Yes the ipad is connected to the computer.  Side note.  This does not happen in xcode 5.

Comment: Thank you.  Does it matter that this happens after everything loads it doesnt make it to done view load